# react-native, the modules point to the same directory in the file system

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm trying to use facebook login button on a React-native android app but I keep having the .iml files created in the root folder of my project everytime I sync with Gradle.

Then I get the message saying "the modules [module1, module2] point to the same directory in the file system. Each module has to have a unique path.

I tried to delete and refresh de .iml file several time but I keep having the same result.

Anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: did you get a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this error, and was able to resolve this by doing File → Invalidated Caches / Restart… → Invalidate & Restart.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the root project in your terminal and run command

```
npm run clean_nm
npm install
```

It will fix the problem

Answer (score -2):

I have this issue. I followed the advice to invalidate caches, but after that, Android Studio throws this error:

> Help please! Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not
>   supported for following modules: react-native-vector-icons,
>   react-native-cookie.

Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

Comment: Please post this as a comment and not as an answer!